# Make VS2012-compatible a VSIX extension developed for VS2013

Tags: wpf, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, vsix

As the title says, I've developed a VSIX package based on the "Visual Studio Package" template project  in VS2013.

It's a very simple extension which adds a decoration layer to the text editor, and the code is [here](https://github.com/tanathos/WhereAmI).

I'm trying to add compatibility for VS2012, with no luck.

I've modified the install target in the .vsixmanifest and indeed, as I launch the installer, it asks me if I want to install to VS2012 too. The extension installs itself well, but I've got an issue as it activates on IWpfTextViewCreationListener (as soon as I open a text file for edit), and it seems something related with the version of a DLL referenced in the project.

What I got in the ActivityLog is:

```
<entry>
    <record>862</record>
    <time>2014/10/28 11:23:29.757</time>
    <type>Error</type>
    <source>Editor or Editor Extension</source>
    <description>System.ComponentModel.Composition.CompositionContractMismatchException: Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type &apos;Recoding.WhereAmI.WhereAmIFactory (ContractName=&quot;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextViewCreationListener&quot;)&apos; to type &apos;Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Editor.IWpfTextViewCreationListener&apos;.&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.CastExportedValue[T](ICompositionElement element, Object exportedValue)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.GetCastedExportedValue[T](Export export)&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportServices.&lt;&gt;c__DisplayClass4`2.&lt;CreateStronglyTypedLazyOfTM&gt;b__1()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()&#x000D;&#x000A;   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.Utilities.GuardedOperations.InstantiateExtension[TExtension,TMetadata](Object errorSource, Lazy`2 provider)</description>
  </entry>
```

It references the Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI.Wpf.dll which is the 12.0, I've tried to mark the reference with "Spefic Version" = false, but the problem remains.

As a side note, I'm not able to run VS2012 in Experimental Mode LOADING the extension. I changed the "Start external program" option of the project to the Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe , and it runs in experimental mode, but without loading the extension. To test it I've to produce the VSIX and install it to the VS2012 (and it's a pain).

Any suggestions on how to proceed? It's really related with the assembly misversion?

Comment: shouldn't your InstallTarget then not be Version="[11.0,]", also try to remove the dependency to Microsoft.VisualStudio.MPF. I normally remove that one to get it for both working

Comment: Yeah, the version you see on github is not aligned to my local, I've already added the install target to match VS2012. The extension installs correctly, the issue is at runtime, as the wpf activates the factory of the extension

Comment: Also, take note I don't have the sdk for VS2012, but only for VS2013. Don't know if is related in some way...

Comment: please see my answer with the 11.0 Assemblies it worked in VS2012 and VS2013 for me with your Addin. About the Experimental Mode, I also have no solution for that

Comment: Can you clarify what did you change in the extension.vsixmanifest to get the extension install in VS2012. I added the code from your extension, but it still offers just VS2013:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change the  Microsoft.VisualStudio.Text.UI.Wpf.dll from Version 12.0 to 11.0.

For down compatibility to Visual Studio 2012 you have to use 11.0 Assemblies.

you can get them via NuGet:

`PM> Install-Package VSSDK.Text.11`

Comment: Yeah, you did it. Never tought I could get these assemblies from NuGet without download the SDK. Thanks a lot, I'm going to update the extension in the Extensions Gallery, I'll give you the credit for this if you're ok with that :)